# Asp.Net c# Window Application

Tags: c#

I'm creating an *Windows Application* for the database backup and I've already added the references in my projects.

But I got the error:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError' does not contain a definition for
>   'Message' and no extension method 'Message' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've already attached the screen shot of the error. Please help me with this issue. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you added the assembly rererence as stated in the other errors?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in two of the errors, you are missing an assembly reference to `System.Data`. Add this at the top of your code file (outside of any class or method) as `using System.Data;` and that should resolve the problem.

Or, right click on the underlined code and use the context menu to automatically add the missing reference.